# Data binding simple variable not working

Tags: asp.net

This is the page code for the control:

```
<asp:TextBox id="someID" maxlength="10" columns="10" runat="server" Text="<%# work %>" />
```

This is how I set up and populate the variable before page is rendered, it is in the code behind, I have tried I think all the variations available for the variable declaration, e.g. public, shared, protected, etc.:

```
Public work As String
work = "987654321"
```

The textbox always comes up blank. referred to this [ms kb page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) for how this work and it has a specific example.

However, it didn't explain anywhere if there is some special way of declaring the variables used in the binding or some special way to set the value of the variable, or is there something needed to allow the `<%#` syntax to work?

Answer (score 0):

Binding doesn't happen automatically.  You have to call `DataBind()` either from Page control or the text control.  Try put it in `Page_Load()` method.